# Left Join Return Joining Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables right now that store data. They are related by an ID value. How can I return all the values from table one including the master value even if it has matches. Here is my basic query.

```
Select MFG.mfgname, SS.subsysname
From Manufacturers MFG left join SubSystem SS
On MFG.id = SS.mfgid
Order by MFG.mfgname, SS.subsysname
```

Here are the tables

```
    MFG Table       
id  mfgname 
1   ABB 
2   Siemens 
3   Vipa    
4   Visolux 

SubSystem table     
id  mfgid   subsysname
1   1   ABB Drives
2   1   ABB Robots
3   1   Advant OCS
4   2   Simatic S5
5   2   Simatic S7
6   3   Vipa System
```

And finally the results and the desired results.

```
Results 
mfgname subsysname
ABB ABB Drives
ABB ABB Robots
ABB Advant OCS
Siemens Simatic S5
Siemens Simatic S7
Vipa    Vipa System
Visolux NULL

Desired Results 
mfgname subsysname
ABB NULL
ABB ABB Drives
ABB ABB Robots
ABB Advant OCS
Siemens NULL
Siemens Simatic S5
Siemens Simatic S7
Vipa    NULL
Vipa    Vipa System
Visolux NULL
```

The Desired results would also return the ABB, Siemens, and Vipa mfgs with a null subsystem name. At this point it doesn't. Hope this made sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using UNION.

```
SELECT  MFG.mfgname,
        SS.subsysname
FROM    Manufacturers MFG
        LEFT JOIN SubSystem SS ON MFG.id = SS.mfgid
UNION
SELECT  MFG.mfgname,
        NULL
FROM    Manufacturers MFG
ORDER BY MFG.mfgname,
        SS.subsysname
```

Comment: Might this perform a little better if you change the `left join` to an `inner join` and the `union` to `union all`, avoiding the need for a distinct sort?

Comment: if `subsysname` is not nullable, you could use inner join and union all